# In C++, is it possible to include all headers in all sub-folders of a folder?

Tags: c++, include, eigen

```
#include <iostream>
#include<eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h> // does not define Eigen::StorageOptions

// need something like this
#include<eigen3/Eigen/src/ everything_in_here >

int main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix<double,2,2> mat;
    std::cout << mat(0,0) <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In there, I'm trying to build a matrix object and it always asks 6 template parameters with error message:

> wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 6)

So I started adding them, 4th one is `Eigen::StorageOptions` and is not defined in the `Matrix.h` header. Also there are too many headers to search. So, can I include all files in there with a single `#include`?

Comment: No, but you can always make a header file that does that for you (though it might not be very efficient, usually only include what you use)

Comment: Ideally, in C++20, we should write `import eigen3;` to simply and efficiently import all header files.

Comment: includes from `/src/` ? `Eigen/Dense` should already be the one header you are looking for

Comment: Although beginners usually try to avoid it (hence regularly request advice on how to include a large number of headers at once) it is generally considered better practice to only include headers that are needed by each source file.   This reduces dependencies, and also reduces incremental build times (e.g. when some headers are edited, it is not necessary to recompile/rebuild the entire project - which can, in large projects save huge amounts of time waiting for a rebuild to finish).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. Only individual files can be included. (Though technically what that means is implementation-defined.) The preprocessor has no filesystem/directory concept. It considers the file names used in `#include` directives only as strings, not paths.

I am also not aware of any compiler extension to support this (although there may be ones).

You can generate the necessary `#include` directives in a script as a preparation step in the build process.

Comment: Can ```#include``` be used in run-time after searching for files in the program?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik No.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik You can write a script in whatever language to add as a preparation step in the build system. It can scan the directory and write the `#include` lines into a header file that you can then include.

Comment: Because its static compilation right? Then I need to produce a C++ code string and compile it in run-time with all file headers listed.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik That's possible, but probably much more work than adding e.g. a Python script to the build system.

Comment: Actually ```eigen``` already has a header-list called ```Dense``` but the IDE I'm using does not find that automatially so I had to write it myself. But was wondering if there was C++-way of doing same.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik If you have a specific problem with your IDE, you should describe that actual problem (in a new question) -- asking about your attempted solution is often an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 8):

You are not supposed to include anything from `Eigen/src/...` directly. If you need only the core components of Eigen, use

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
```

If you want to include everything related to dense matrix operations (e.g., decompositions and the Geometry module):

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
```

If you also want to include the Sparse module

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
// or this to include Dense+Sparse:
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
```

You should make sure via compilation options, that the top-level Eigen-directory is in your include-path, e.g. on many Linux-environments, add `-I/usr/include/eigen3` as an argument. Your IDE probably also has an option for that. If you use something like CMake there are lots of related questions for that.

If for whatever reason this does not work or you just need a quick-and-dirty work-around, you can write

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core> //etc
```

Comment: Yep, this is the way. Just wondered if C++ has some shortcut of including a lot of headers.